# How to add a subtotal for separate products in mini-cart?

Tags: cart, mini-cart

I am using a slightly modified modern theme for my store. Most of my store is using a 3 column layout with a mini-cart in the right column.
By default the products in the mini-cart have a thumbnail, product name, quantity and unit price:

[image: default mini-cart]

What I would like to do add a separate subtotal for every product in the 
cart...something like in the picture:

[image: mini-cart]

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the row total of the item

Use the following code in your `checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml` file to get the **Row Total** of the item.

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal())
```

Comment: Where exactly do I use this code?

Comment: Enable the path hint and check which file is rendered.

Comment: @DavorPehchevski i thing you have to copy the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml` file and paste it in your theme `app/design/frontend/yournamespace/yourtheme/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`

Comment: I know that the file rendering the sidebar cart is  `app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`.
There is no need to copy the file from the base theme because the contents are the same.

But I need to edit that file so that I can achieve the result from the question.
Can I use
`Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal())` 
in that file? If I can, where exactly?

Comment: @DavorPehchevski you can this also `$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal())` before this `<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>` line . It may be in line 125

Comment: That doesn't do anyhing...

Comment: Can you show your code which your tried

Comment: I actually had a typo :) `<?pnp` instead of `<?php` .

It works this way...now I'll just have to style it...

[image](http://prntscr.com/7l5nnx)

Comment: you got output or not ?

Comment: I edited the previous comment...you can see the output there.

Thanks a lot!